# I have a 64-bit server but PHP 7.2 (apparently) installs in 32-bit mode

Tags: php, drupal

I have a Debian 9 (stretch) server. I purged all PHP packages and installed PHP 7.2 afresh because **PHP_INT_SIZE** was giving a value of **4** (32 bit) instead of the expected **8** (64 bit). This did not change even after the fresh install. Would be grateful if someone could help me sort this out.

I am also running Drupal (up-to-date, rel 8.5.3) which pointed out this issue in the first place. This is the Drupal warning :
[image]

lscpu confirms that I have a 64-bit config. This is the output :

```
#lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU            3050  @ 2.13GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2133.299
BogoMIPS:              4266.59
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              2048K
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf eagerfpu pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm tpr_shadow dtherm
```

Comment: This is just a warning. Click **"continue anyway"** https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/261584/15055

Comment: It is indeed a warning in Drupal, but I would like my PHP to run in 64-bit mode as it should by default! Which is why this post.